# Increment HTML with button in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm doing my first project in React and I would like some help, as I'm a very beginner. I would like to make a button that adds HTML to the page. When the "Add Education" button is pressed, new input fields are added to the page. I'm trying to manipulate the states, but I can't get enough control to increment the `formEducation` variable with more HTML when the button is pressed.

education.js:

```js
import '../styles/education.css';
import { useState } from 'react';

function Education(){
    const [formEducation, setFormEducation] = useState(
        <div className="form">
            <div className="input" type="text">
                <label htmlFor="inputInstitution">Instituition name: </label>
                <input type="text" name="inputInstitution" placeholder="Enter the name of your school or university" required></input>
            </div>
            <div className="input">
                <label htmlFor="inputCourse">Course Name: </label>
                <input name="inputCourse" type="text" placeholder="Enter the name of your course" required></input>
            </div>
            <div className="input">
                <label htmlFor="dateInput">Date of conclusion: </label>
                <input name="dateInput" type="date" required></input>
            </div>
        </div>
      );
    function Append(){
        
    }
    return (
        <div className="background" id="education">
            <h2>Education</h2>
            { formEducation }
            <button type="button" onClick={ Append }>Add Education</button>
        </div>
    );
}
export default Education;
```

I know how to manipulate the DOM, but I would like to manipulate this state variable.